# jsTree plugin renaming error when renaming more than one item

Tags: rename, jstree

I have a problem with the jsTree plugin crrm when I try to rename **more than one** item in the tree.

Problem: When I rename more than one a white box appears over the name and I can't see what I'm typing any more. This doesn't happen the first time.
The length of the "white box" that covers it is the length of the current node name. I can see my typing if I type past the length of the box as it'll appear on the right.

And the change will work - but I can't see it when I'm typing.

Anyone know what's up?